# Ways to speed up rolling weighted mean on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large `DataFrame`, on which I need to calculate the rolling row-wise weighted average.

I know I can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000, 50))
weights = [1/9, 2/9, 1/3, 2/9, 1/9]  
rolling_mean = df.rolling(5, axis=1).apply(lambda seq: np.average(seq, weights=weights))
```

The issue is that this takes around 40 seconds on my PC. Is there any way to speed up this computation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code**

*Creating a new dataframe of multiplying df by weights[0], then shifting df by one and multiplying by weights[1], then shifting df by two and multiplying by weights[2]*, and repeating this process, then adding all of the created dataframes together, will speed up the process.

```
sum([df.shift(num, axis=1) * w for num, w in enumerate(weights)])
```

it take 0.05986 sec

Comment: Please add an explanation to go along with your answer.

Comment: @jared I first add the code and then modify the explanation. This is because I need a translator to explain in English.

Comment: @AndrejKesely you are right

Comment: @PandaKim Also I'd remove the `[ ]`, to not hold the dataframes in memory. `sum(df.shift(num, axis=1) * w for num, w in enumerate(weights))` is enough.

Comment: exactly running `sum([df.shift(num, axis=1) * w for num, w in enumerate(weights)])
` returns `nan`

Answer (score 3):

Quick benchmark using the above answers:

```py
from timeit import timeit

import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000, 50))

weights = [1 / 9, 2 / 9, 1 / 3, 2 / 9, 1 / 9]


def rolling_normal(df):
    return df.rolling(5, axis=1).apply(lambda seq: np.average(seq, weights=weights))


def rolling_numba(df):
    return df.rolling(5, axis=1).apply(weighted_mean, engine="numba", raw=True)


def weighted_mean(seq):
    weights = [1 / 9, 2 / 9, 1 / 3, 2 / 9, 1 / 9]
    return np.average(seq, weights=weights)


def rollin_panda_kim(df):
    return sum(df.shift(num, axis=1) * w for num, w in enumerate(weights))


def rolling_safffh(df):
    @nb.njit
    def weighted_average(arr, weights):
        n = len(arr)
        result = np.empty(n - 4)  # The size of the resulting rolling window
        for i in range(n - 4):
            result[i] = np.average(arr[i : i + 5], weights=weights)
        return result

    # Apply the weighted_average function to the DataFrame
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.apply_along_axis(weighted_average, axis=1, arr=df.values, weights=weights),
        columns=df.columns[4:],  # Adjust the columns to match the rolling window size
    )


# warm-up numba
rolling_numba(df)
rolling_safffh(df)


t1 = timeit("rolling_normal(x)", setup="x=df.copy()", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("rolling_numba(x)", setup="x=df.copy()", number=1, globals=globals())
t3 = timeit("rollin_panda_kim(x)", setup="x=df.copy()", number=1, globals=globals())
t4 = timeit("rolling_safffh(x)", setup="x=df.copy()", number=1, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
print(t4)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 5700X/Python 3.11):

```py
21.627028748000157
0.3747533499990823
0.008139017998473719
0.40484421200017096
```

@PandaKim solution is fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) installed and then specify `engine="numba"` and `raw=True` as keywords to the [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000, 50))

def weighted_mean(seq):
    weights = [1/9, 2/9, 1/3, 2/9, 1/9]
    return np.average(seq, weights=weights)

rolling_mean = df.rolling(5, axis=1).apply(weighted_mean, engine="numba", raw=True)
```

The basic principle of numba is explained in the pandas documentation page [Enhancing performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#numba-jit-compilation):

> ### Numba (JIT compilation)
>
> An alternative to statically compiling Cython code is to use a dynamic
> just-in-time (JIT) compiler with Numba.
>
> Numba allows you to write a pure Python function which can be JIT
> compiled to native machine instructions, similar in performance to C,
> C++ and Fortran, by decorating your function with @jit.
>
> Numba works by generating optimized machine code using the LLVM
> compiler infrastructure at import time, runtime, or statically (using
> the included pycc tool). Numba supports compilation of Python to run
> on either CPU or GPU hardware and is designed to integrate with the
> Python scientific software stack.

### Benchmark

On my machine this solution takes 1.087 s. Panda Kim's solution is superior, taking only 0.058 s.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up the computation of the rolling row-wise weighted average on a large DataFrame, you can leverage Numba.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numba as nb

# Sample data
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000, 50))
weights = [1/9, 2/9, 1/3, 2/9, 1/9]

# Define a Numba JIT-compiled function for the weighted average
@nb.njit
def weighted_average(arr, weights):
    n = len(arr)
    result = np.empty(n - 4)  # The size of the resulting rolling window
    for i in range(n - 4):
        result[i] = np.average(arr[i:i+5], weights=weights)
    return result

# Apply the weighted_average function to the DataFrame
rolling_mean = pd.DataFrame(
    np.apply_along_axis(weighted_average, axis=1, arr=df.values, weights=weights),
    columns=df.columns[4:],  # Adjust the columns to match the rolling window size
)

print(rolling_mean)
```

Comment: Benchmark for this solution: 0.393 s (on my machine).